# Accessing member variables through boost lambda placeholder

Tags: c++, variables, lambda, member

I'm trying to print the second member variable of all items in an stl map using a lambda expression

```
map<int, int> theMap;
for_each(theMap.begin(), theMap.end(), 
         cout << bind(&pair<int, int>::second, _1) << constant(" "));
```

but this is not compiling. I essentially want to de-reference the placeholder. Any idea what I'm missing here?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::map` will add `const` to its key; this is to prevent messing up the ordering. Your pair should be:

```
std::pair<const int, int>
```

Like dirkgently suggests, use the `value_type` to always get the correct type. The verbosity is alleviated with a typedef:

```
typedef std::map<int, int> int_map;

int_map::value_type::second
```

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
for_each(theMap.begin(), theMap.end(), 
         cout << bind(&map<int, int>::value_type::second, _1) << constant(" "));
```

Comment: Great, thanks dirkgently and GMan, this works and makes sense when combined with what the compiler was saying. Cheers!